# Golang project directory structure

Tags: go, gopath

I have some confusion regarding Golang directory structure.

Base on the book *The Way to Go* by Ivo Balbaert, project code should be placed into `src`, and recommends the following directory structure.

```
    ├──src/
    |  ├──main.go
    |  ├──say/
    |  |  ├──say.go
    |  |  ├──say_test.go
    ├──bin/
    |  ├──say
    └──pkg/
       └──linux_amd64/
          └──say.a
```

but I found that many packages in `github.com`, have no `src` directory.

For example:

https://github.com/facebookgo/grace

https://github.com/astaxie/beego

So, I don't know whether `src` directory is needed.

I have some project, their have inter-dependency.
They are managed in a private GitLab repository.

How can I organized them?

Comment: What your book is probably describing is the tree of the GOPATH directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm foolish

Comment: Probably late but another great example for go project boilerplate is qiangxue's starter kit - https://github.com/qiangxue/golang-restful-starter-kit

Answer (score 31):

[This](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091) article by *Ben Johnson* has guided me on this when I was starting with Go.

It's generally good to start with something like this (assuming you are inside your project directory like `$GOPATH/src/myproject`:

```
├──cmd/ -- this is where you compose several packages in to main package
|  ├──foo -- an example would be `foo`
|  |  ├──main.go
├──pkg/ -- this is where put your reusable packages 
|  ├──pkg1 -- reusable package 1
|  ├──pkg2 -- reusable package 2
├──otherpackage1
|  ├── ...
├──otherpackage2
|  ├── ...
```

You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/go-kit/examples/tree/master/addsvc) example from [`go-kit`](https://github.com/go-kit/kit) for this kind of project structure.

Sometimes it will depend on your needs. On our workflow, we are using a hot code reload tool called [fresh](https://github.com/pilu/fresh), so we needed to put the `main.go` on the project root so that the tool can detect all the file changes and rebuild the source code.

```
├──app/
|  ├──app.go
├──model/ -- 
|  ├──model.go
├──store
|  ├──store.go
├──main.go -- this is where the app starts
├──...
```

On the `app.go` package, I have something like `func Run() error` which starts the application. On the `main.go`, I am just calling the function:

```
...
func main(){
    log.Fatal(app.Run())
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Now there are [new ways](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) to organize Go projects.
The [GitHub golang-standards repository](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) says:

> This is a basic layout for Go application projects. It represents the
> most common directory structure with a number of small enhancements
> along with several supporting directories common to any real world
> application.
>
> This project layout is intentionally generic and it doesn't try to
> impose a specific Go package structure.

Or you can follow this [slides](https://talks.golang.org/2014/organizeio.slide#9):

```
$GOPATH/
    src/
        github.com/user/repo/
            mypkg/
                mysrc1.go
                mysrc2.go
            cmd/mycmd/
                main.go
    bin/
        mycmd
```

Comment: Although the repo contains a couple of interesting points, it seems to be _not_ an official guidance by golang. In other words, it is just "yet another" opinion on the topic, so I would not position it as a "new way" as "new way" sounds like an ultimate guidance that overrules existing ones.

Answer (score 11):

**Update 11/23/2023**

Summary from [Organizing a Go module](https://go.dev/doc/modules/layout) on go.dev

> A common question developers new to Go have is “How do I organize my Go project?”, in terms of the layout of files and folders. The goal of this document is to provide some guidelines that will help answer this question.

- **Basic package**

  - A basic Go package has all its code in the project’s root directory. The project consists of a single module, which consists of a single package. The package name matches the last path component of the module name. For a very simple package requiring a single Go file, the project structure is:

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  modname.go
  modname_test.go
```

- **Basic command**

  - A basic executable program (or command-line tool) is structured according to its complexity and code size. The simplest program can consist of a single Go file where `func main` is defined. Larger programs can have their code split across multiple files, all declaring `package main`:

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  auth.go
  auth_test.go
  client.go
  main.go
```

- **Package or command with supporting packages**

  - Larger packages or commands may benefit from splitting off some functionality into supporting packages. Initially, it’s recommended placing such packages into a directory named internal; this prevents other modules from depending on packages we don’t necessarily want to expose and support for external uses.

```
project-root-directory/
  internal/
    auth/
      auth.go
      auth_test.go
    hash/
      hash.go
      hash_test.go
  go.mod
  modname.go
  modname_test.go
```

- **Multiple packages**

  - A module can consist of multiple importable packages; each package has its own directory, and can be structured hierarchically.

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  modname.go
  modname_test.go
  auth/
    auth.go
    auth_test.go
    token/
      token.go
      token_test.go
  hash/
    hash.go
  internal/
    trace/
      trace.go
```

- **Multiple commands**

  - Multiple programs in the same repository will typically have separate directories

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  internal/
    ... shared internal packages
  prog1/
    main.go
  prog2/
    main.go
```

- **Packages and commands in the same repository**

  - Sometimes a repository will provide both importable packages and installable commands with related functionality.

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  modname.go
  modname_test.go
  auth/
    auth.go
    auth_test.go
  internal/
    ... internal packages
  cmd/
    prog1/
      main.go
    prog2/
      main.go
```

- **Server project**

  - Server projects typically won’t have packages for export, since a server is usually a self-contained binary (or a group of binaries). Therefore, it’s recommended to keep the Go packages implementing the server’s logic in the internal directory. Moreover, since the project is likely to have many other directories with non-Go files, it’s a good idea to keep all Go commands together in a cmd directory

```
project-root-directory/
  go.mod
  internal/
    auth/
      ...
    metrics/
      ...
    model/
      ...
  cmd/
    api-server/
      main.go
    metrics-analyzer/
      main.go
    ...
  ... the project's other directories with non-Go code
```

---

Here is another project layout sample [Simple Go project layout with modules](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/simple-go-project-layout-with-modules/)

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── config.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── clientlib
│   ├── lib.go
│   └── lib_test.go
├── cmd
│   ├── modlib-client
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── modlib-server
│       └── main.go
├── internal
│   └── auth
│       ├── auth.go
│       └── auth_test.go
└── serverlib
    └── lib.go
```

Some answer points out the [go standard layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout), however, there is one issue [this is not a standard Go project layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/issues/117) by Russ Cox

> There are two problems with this GitHub repo:

> - it claims to host Go standards and does not, in the sense that these are in no way official standards
> - the project-layout standard it puts forth is far too complex and not a standard

> Regarding "why not tell us the standard Go project layout and we'll update the doc?", that only addresses point 2. Standards would be in the main Go project doc tree if there were standards. The standard for project layout would also be a lot shorter. I appreciate your trying to provide a useful resource, but calling it 'golang-standards' is claiming more than it is.

> But for the record, the minimal standard layout for an importable Go repo is really:

> - Put a LICENSE file in your root
> - Put a go.mod file in your root
> - Put Go code in your repo, in the root or organized into a directory tree as you see fit

> That's it. That's the "standard".

---

**Update at 11/30/2021**

Here is a summary from [How to structure Go code](https://developer20.com/how-to-structure-go-code/)

- Before we start

  - `doc.go` file puts the general description of the package
  - `Readme` file a general overview of this project
  - When you have more documentation to provide put them into the `docs` folder
  - For linting use golangci-lint. Enable all linters that seem to be reasonable for your project
- The flat structure (single package)

  ```
  courses/
    main.go
    server.go
    user_profile.go
    lesson.go
    course.go
  ```

  - When to create a new package?

    - When you have more than one way of starting your application
    - When you want to extract more detailed implementation
    - When you started to add a common prefix to closely related things
- Modularisation

  - Organising by kind

```
.
├── handlers
│   ├── course.go
│   ├── lecture.go
│   ├── profile.go
│   └── user.go
├── main.go
├── models
│   ├── course.go
│   ├── lecture.go
│   └── user.go
├── repositories
│   ├── course.go
│   ├── lecture.go
│   └── user.go
├── services
│   ├── course.go
│   └── user.go
└── utils
    └── stings.go
```

- Organising by components

```
.
├── course
│   ├── httphandler.go
│   ├── model.go
│   ├── repository.go
│   └── service.go
├── main.go
└── profile
    ├── httphandler.go
    ├── model.go
    ├── repository.go
    └── service.go
```

- Clean Architecture

  - You have 4 layers of your application or module (depending on how big your codebase is): Domain, Application, Ports, Adapters. In some sources, names may differ.

Comment: Do these directories have to be in $HOME/src? And how are the modules referred to? Thanks!

Comment: These directories does NOT in `$HOME/src`, the modules could be referred by relative path @nroose

Answer (score 3):

The src directory is not needed and in fact a lot of public repositories do not use this structure.

There is a few different way of organizing your project. If you plan on having your project used by an other repository, like lib. I would recommend using a cmd struct something like this. This would also be the recommended way of doing it if there would be more then one way of starting the application. (multipliable main.go files)

```
├──cmd/
|  ├──(application name)
|  |  ├──main.go
└──say/
   ├──say.go
   └──say_test.go
```

Otherwise for example if it is a standalone application. You can place the main.go in the root of the repository.

bin and pkg you can keep in the root and add this to .gitignore. (assuming you are using git)

Comment: bin and pkg should be in the root of `GOPATH`, they shouldn't be in the project directory at all, just like src.

Comment: The golang standards `golang-standards/project-layout` on [github](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) agrees on the `src` directory.

Comment: @Compree You mean disagrees? There's an explicit section named [Directories You Shouldn't Have](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout#directories-you-shouldnt-have) which includes `/src`

Comment: Yes, Seraf, you are right. My unclear comment was that src is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

The book describes the directory structure after checkout. It would have been helpful if the book included the .git directory.

$GOPATH/src is required for imports to work.

```
    ├──src/
    |  ├──.git
    |  |  ├──...
    |  ├──main.go
    |  ├──say/
    |  |  ├──say.go
    |  |  ├──say_test.go
    ├──bin/
    |  ├──say
    └──pkg/
       └──linux_amd64/
          └──say.a
```

In practice, main.go would actually be in a path that reflects the remote git repository, for instance

```
.   
├── bin
│   └── say
├── pkg
│   └── linux_amd64
│       └── github.com
│           └── pschultz
│               └── hello-world
│                   └── say.a
└── src
    └── github.com
        └── pschultz
            └── hello-world
                ├── .git
                │   └── ...
                ├── main.go
                └── say
                    ├── say.go
                    └── say_test.go
```